# Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3

Tags: apple-push-notifications, websphere-8, okhttp, http2, javapns

My code connects to apns for push notification. Am using clevertap library from git(https://github.com/CleverTap/apns-http2). It uses okhttp3 for the connection. When I run code on IBM WAS 8.5.5 and am receiving an exception. Details below. Can you pls help me on how to address this? Am trying with Synchronous mode of sending push message. I use Java 1.7, WAS 8.5.5. Pls let me know if you need more details.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform@aeaa4bd5, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:187)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:60)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:718)
        at com.clevertap.apns.clients.SyncOkHttpApnsClient.<init>(SyncOkHttpApnsClient.java:79)
```

**Edit**:

There were some solutions suggesting to re-install the certificate etc. But now, I don't get the trust store issue. But getting SSLHandshakeException.  Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. I googled for the problem, but most of the solutions are with p12 option, with certificate not extracted correctly. But am using a p8 file here.

Comment: A similar issue was report here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2427 It looks like you're using an IBM JDK too; perhaps using a newer release of OkHttp would help here.

Comment: @wtlucy - Thanks. I had already checked the thread and I was using the latest version 3.9.2 of the library. There were some solutions suggesting to re-install the certificate etc. But now, I don't get the trust store issue. But getting SSLHandshakeException.  Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. I googled for the problem, but most of the solutions are with p12 option, with certificate not extracted correctly. But am using a p8 file here.

Comment: Your handshake issue is probably related to cipher selection: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3173  Perhaps you could test running with openJDK

Comment: it looks like SSL_ or TLS_ prefix problem was addressed with okhttp on version 3.7 and am using latest 3.9.2 of the jar. My environment is fixed. I do not have a option to use openJDK.